# Devise gives me an 'email cannot be blank' error even though email is not blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am doing two things with my user registration with Devise.

1. [Two step confirmation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Two-Step-Confirmation) - where all the user is required to do is to enter their email address at first.
2. I have moved the registration/new form to my `welcome#index` view.

Even though I correctly entered the email address, and I see that it is included in the `params` hash in the log:

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-06-05 20:35:43 -0500
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"0qWg/RxG+XyDqdsdadww=", "email"=>"abc@test.com", "commit"=>"Sign Me Up!"}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  User Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT 1 FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('') LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
  Rendered devise/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (9.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 65ms (Views: 54.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
1 error prohibited this user from being saved:
Email can't be blank
```

My initial registration form looks like this:

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :class => "send-with-ajax", :url => user_registration_path(resource)) do |f| %>
            <%= devise_error_messages! %>
              <%= f.email_field :email, :name => :email, :id => "form-email", :placeholder => "your-email@address.com", :input_html => {:autofocus => true} %>
              <%= f.submit :label => "Submit", :value => "Sign Me Up!"  %>
          <% end %>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possible explanation:

Your email field is in the `params` hash as `params[:email]`, while your create action in the controller probably is expecting it in `params[:resource][:email]`. When you remove the `:name => :email` assignment, then the email moves back to `params[:resource][:email]`.

You have posted this hash:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"0qWg/RxG+XyDqdsdadww=", "email"=>"abc@test.com", "commit"=>"Sign Me Up!"}
```

Can you see a difference in what it looks like when it works?

Comment: You are absolutely right! `Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"0qWg/RxG+Xkjhgjsdsxaxcu/RL1yuBgtiVN1fw=", "user"=>{"email"=>"abc@test.com"}, "commit"=>"Sign Me Up!"}`

Answer (score 1):

I just figured it out, it seems the `:name` attribute in my form helper for the email field was causing issues.

This was the original field:

```
<%= f.email_field :email, :name => :email, :id => "form-email", :placeholder => "your-email@address.com", :input_html => {:autofocus => true} %>
```

I changed it to:

```
<%= f.email_field :email, :id => "form-email", :placeholder => "your-email@address.com", :input_html => {:autofocus => true} %>
```

That fixed it, but I don't know why.