# Using collection_select and getting an unexpected error from sqlite3 - anyone know why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, sqlite

I am relatively new to Ruby on Rails and am having an issue using `collection_select` and getting my new form to submit successfully.  Some background on my code:

- I have a  User model and a Payment model; a User `has_many` payments, and a Payment `belongs_to` user.
- I am using *Devise* to manage user logins, and when a user is logged in they can add a new payment via a form.
- I am using `collection_select` to generate a list of email addresses associated with the current user that can be selected via the form.

I am having two issues, which I believe both stem from my incorrect usage of collection_select:

1. When I select an email address on the form and submit, I get an error message that the email address can't be blank, even when I have submitted a non-blank entry.  The error message is a result of validation in my Payment model, `validates :email, :presence => true`
2. I temporarily commented out the `:email` validation line in my Payment model, and now am getting the error message: `SQLite3::SQLException: cannot start a transaction within a transaction: begin transaction`.

I have spent awhile trying to figure out what I am doing wrong without luck; I was not able to find this issue in other posts on Stackoverflow.  I am guessing this is a simple mistake but can't seem to figure it out.  Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

/app/models/payment.rb

```
require 'valid_email'

class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  attr_accessible :amount, :description, :email, :frequency, :paid, :user_id
  belongs_to :user

  #validates :email, :presence => true, :email => true (commented out as described above)
  validates :amount, :presence => true, :format => { :with => /^\d+??(?:\.\d{0,2})?$/ }, :numericality => {:greater_than => 0, :less_than => 100000}
  validates :description, :presence => true
end
```

/app/models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
  has_many :payments
end
```

/app/controllers/payments_controller.rb (just create and new):

```
class PaymentsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  def create
    @payment = current_user.payments.new(params[:payment])
    @payment_current_user = current_user.payments.all

    respond_to do |format|
      if @payment.save
        format.html { redirect_to payments_url, :flash => { notice: 'Payment was successfully created.' } }
        format.json { render json: @payment, status: :created, location: @payment }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @payment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
  def new
    @payment = current_user.payments.new

    # get list of current_user's email addresses in form
    @payment_current_user = current_user.payments.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @payment }
    end
  end
end
```

/app/views/payments/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@payment) do |f| %>
  <form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="field">
      <div class="control-group">
        <%= f.label :email, "Lendee's Email", class: "control-label" %><br />
        <div class="controls">

          <%= collection_select :payment, :user_id, @payment_current_user, :email, :email, {:include_blank => "Please select"} %>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
      <div class="actions">
        <div class="controls">  
          <%= f.submit %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
<% end %>
```

**Full error message, which comes up after I click Submit:**

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in PaymentsController#create
SQLite3::SQLException: cannot start a transaction within a transaction: begin transaction
```

- **Application trace associated with error:**

  app/controllers/payments_controller.rb:52:in `block in create'
  app/controllers/payments_controller.rb:51:in`create'
- **Request parameters associated with error:**

  {"utf8"=>"✓",
   "authenticity_token"=>"K8+NnWHIIxVfcC5IvhLhoSKOzuScFrpnHOPTt1pVdpA=",
   "payment"=>{"user_id"=>"new@gmail.com",
   "amount"=>"d",
   "frequency"=>"biweekly",
   "description"=>"adf",
   "paid"=>"Pending"},
   "commit"=>"Create Payment"}

Comment: Not sure, but I found it odd that the request parameters include `"payment"=>{"user_id"=>"new@gmail.com"` ... perhaps that is the "transaction within a transaction" referred to in the error message?

Comment: if you were expecting the id of the User (`"user_id"=>"42"`), then you need to change the collection select to `collection_select :payment, :user_id, @payment_current_user, :id, :email, {:include_blank => "Please select"}` (change the first `:email` to `:id`)

Comment: @JoshuaScott Thanks for your comment.  The reason I used `:email` rather than `:id` was because I thought (?) that may be why I was getting the validation error - in other words, I assumed that the form validation is relative to the value provided in the option tag.  In this case, the HTML generated is `<option value="new@gmail.com">new@gmail.com</option>`, so I assumed that the form validation checks `value="new@gmail.com"`.  Regardless, making that change does not fix the error message I am getting.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Which line is 52 in payments_controller?

Comment: @JoshuaScott Line 52 is `if @payment.save`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my issue.  As I mentioned in the problem description, I was getting an error message via `validates :email, :presence => true` that *Email can't be blank*, even when an email address was selected.  I found [this post on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10907947/devise-gives-me-an-email-cannot-be-blank-error-even-though-email-is-not-blank), which helped me realize that I was expecting `:email`, not `:user_id`, to be submitted in the form.

As a result, I changed my code to the following:

`<%= f.collection_select :email, current_user.payments, :email, :email, {:include_blank => "Please select"} %>`

Note the above also reflects me building an array of current_user payments in the view, rather than from an instantiated variable in the model.